# Short question about submanifolds

Tags: submanifold

Which of these subsets $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a submanifold?

a. $M = \{(x,y)\,|\, x^2+y^2=1\}$

b. $M = \{(x,y)\,|\, x=0 \mbox { oder } y= 0\}$

c. $M = \mathbb {Q}^2$

I'm kind of sure that a is a submanifold and that c is not. I'm not sure about b but I think that it is a submanifold. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (b) is not: consider the origin $(0,0)$.

If you take a neighborhood of the origin, it is not locally an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.